# Javascript Abstract Member

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm not sure if the title even accurately describes what I'm trying to do here, but here's the code representing the problem:

```
var spriteDefinitions = {};

function Sprite(x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}

spriteDefinitions.Player = function(x, y, state) {
   Sprite.call(this, x, y);
   this.state = state;
}

spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype = new Sprite();
spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype.constructor = spriteDefinitions.Player;
spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype.states = new Array();
spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype.states[0] = "state 0";
spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype.states[1] = "state 1";
spriteDefinitions.Player.prototype.statesEnum = {Right: 0,Left: 1};

var player1 = new spriteDefinitions.Player(50, 90, spriteDefinitions.Player.statesEnum.Left);
var player2 = new spriteDefinitions.Player(100, 100, spriteDefinitions.Player.statesEnum.Right);
```

The creation of player1 gets an error because Player.statesEnum is undefined. Player is supposed to be a class inheriting from Sprite. And Sprite should be able to access the states of all derived classes (an abstract member). But the derived classes actually define what the states are. How do I properly make statesEnum apply to all instances of Player?  I assume I'm going to have the same problem with all the Player.prototype members.  In a normal OO language, I think these would be abstract members, but I'm not clear on how to do this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want `stateEnum` to be available on the constructor, not on the instances. With prototype, you can define what properties instances inherit.

However, if you want `spriteDefinitions.Player.statesEnum` to be available, just define it as such:

```
spriteDefinitions.Player.statesEnum = {Right: 0,Left: 1};
```

Functions are objects which can take properties just as well. Note that this does not make instances have `statusEnum` available; for that you can use prototype.

Comment: I have a hard time grasping the exact meaning of prototype. What you suggests works for statesEnum, but I'm afraid I might run into problems with the states array.  I have code that refers to this.states on an instance of Player.  Is that going to work if I make states a member of  Player, or should I leave it as a member of Player.prototype?  Or will neither work?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: If you store it as a prototype property, instances will have the property available and you can access it like `this.something`. If you add it to the constructor function, only that function will have the property available (it is "static"). I'm not entirely sure why you have `statusEnum` *and* `states`. What advantage would you like to gain from that?

Comment: I see that I want to leave the states array on the prototype because when I'm referring to "this.states" from an instance of Sprite, it works better on the prototype.  I don't know why, but I'm just having a really hard time developing a mental model of JavaScript's OO mechanisms.

Comment: The example code is a bit contrived.  In my actual implementation, states is actually an array of complex objects and statesEnum is a way to refer to a state by name instead of by index.  Does that make sense?  I want to create a sprite and put it in a particular state, but when the generic code is running, it stores the currently active state in a numeric "state" variable which is a simple index into the array of states.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: If I understand you correctly, both `states` and `stateEnum` do not change among instances. Only the current state a `Player` instance as does. I think it might be a good idea to define the possible states and the enum separately, and only define the current state as a property of the instance. Also you can use key/value objects instead of arrays - they seem to fit neatly here. (And, please only capitalize constructor functions for consistency.) http://jsbin.com/iyimiz/edit

Comment: I think that's what I've done.  The 1 change I made, per your suggestion, is to remove ".prototype" from before the statesEnum assignment.  Am I missing something else?  (Oh, and in my actual implementation this.state is on Sprite, not on Player.)

Comment: Is a key value object one defined like {a: 1, b: 2}?  If so, that's what I usually use.  But in this case, I wanted to keep an array of states numerically indexed because sometimes I may want to be able to loop through states, or switch to the "next" or "previous" state.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: In that case I think removing `.prototype` so that it is stored on the constructor rather than on instances suffices.